# Set width of submit button in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Basic question. There is a form submit button:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="submit" colspan="3">
        <input class="design1" type="submit" value="Let's get started"  />
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.design1{
background-color:#3c3c3c;
color: #e5e5e5;
padding:5px;
}

.design1:hover {
background-color:#016a70;
color: #f0f0f0;
padding:5px;
}

.design1:active {
background-color:#016a70;
color: #f0f0f0;
padding:5px;
}
```

How can I make the button as wide as the text? It seems it is as wide as the middle column of the table. I tried to use the *width* attribute, but in vain.

Comment: [Looks good to me](http://jsfiddle.net/NaPMd/)

Comment: He didn't provide us with the whole table so it will look good on its own. @erdomester can you add some more code so we can analyze the issue.

Comment: Try to use width on td element.

Comment: I set td width earlier in the code, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try attribute maxsize="[number of chars]" or size="[number of chars]" for the input. Could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your css file, work fine

```
.submit input{width:150px;
 height:100px;}
```